# Можно ли загрузить изображение в ShareLatex? (latex онлайн)

Tags: latex

Возможно есть какие-то шаблоны кода или можно загрузить напрямую? Если можно, то нужен ли для этого какой-то особенный формат? Или это вообще невозможно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно. И там есть [документация](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Including_images_in_ShareLaTeX) про рисунки, шаблоны (например, при создании простого проекта там есть в примере картинка), можно загрузить картинки в проект напрямую. Там есть специальная кнопка для этого (отметил красным кружком на рисунке). Судя по всему, картинки туда можно и растровые png, jpg и еще pdf (если в настройках проекта для компиляции будете использовать pdflatex - он стоит по умолчанию), и векторные eps (если планируете использовать для компиляции latex). Правда, я не понял, можно ли потом после latex выходной dvi-файл обработать с dvips и ps2pdf.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: Попробовал latex - кажется, они сами прогоняют всю цепочку latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf. Т.к. на выходе не DVI, а PDF.